# Update stripe PaymentRequest 'on' event on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments

I am using `stripe` PaymentRequestButton to add apple pay and google pay now for that we need `stripe` PaymentRequest object. Then we listen to some events using

`PaymentRequest.on('paymentmethod, async (e)=>{ // Here are my states etc })`

Now, this is inside a useEffect and that `useEffect` is dependant on `state` such as `amount`. But changing `amount` doesn't affect this event and I want to update the `eventListeners`

Here is my code

```
let pr = null;

const StripeCheckoutForm = ({ amount, subscription, websiteName }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();

  const [paymentRequest, setPaymentRequest] = useState(null);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stripe) {
      pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
        country: "CA",
        currency: "cad",
        requestPayerName: true,
        requestPayerEmail: true,
        total: { label: websiteName, amount: 1000 },
      });

      pr.canMakePayment().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          setPaymentRequest(pr);
        }
      });

      // Code inside this block doesn't change on state change. 
      // It runs on the state values with which it was mounted.
      // I tried unmounting, cleaning functions, etc but that doesn't work

      pr.on("paymentmethod", async (e) => {
       
          const functions = firebase.functions();
          console.log(subscription);
          if (subscription) {
            console.log("Subscription");
           
            e.complete("success");
          } else {
            console.log("One time");
            
          }
      
      });

      pr.on("cancel", async (e) => {
        setErrorMessage("Payment box cancelled");
      });
    }
  }, [stripe, subscription, amount, websiteName]);

  return (
    <div className="stripe-checkout-form-component">
      <div className="payment-request-buttons-container">
        {paymentRequest && (
          <PaymentRequestButtonElement options={{ paymentRequest }} />
        )}
        <div className="payment-request-error">{errorMessage}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How are you passing/updating the amount to the `StripeCheckoutForm` ? you need to use `useState`. Like declaring `const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1000);` in the component calling StripeCheckoutForm and whenever you update the amount you need to call `setAmount(newValue)`

Comment: amount, subscription and websiteName are states.

Comment: I agree, the callback function (i.e. handler) passed to `PaymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', handler)` doesn't get updated on state changes. And calling `PaymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', handler)` the second time when state changes, doesn't overwrite this event listener, but appends it. So the `handler` will be called twice, once with old state parameters, the second time with new state parameters. This can result in a customer being charged twice or other errors. We need Stripe to comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer on GitHub](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues/126#issuecomment-1126255830) resolves this issue!

Quoting it here, just in case:

> This is not in the official documentation from what I can tell, but I was able to find a way to remove any unwanted additional listeners.
>
> Method 1: You can call `paymentRequest.removeAllListeners()` to remove
> all existing listeners and then reattach a listener of your choice. I
> believe this removes all callbacks from the paymentRequest though,
> which may not be the desired behavior if you have other listeners such
> as on click, or on token that you want to keep around.
>
> Method 2: You can also check to see if the paymentRequest object
> already has a listener of a certain type attached to it, and just
> remove that specific listener in that case.

```
if (paymentRequest.hasRegisteredListener('paymentmethod')) {  
  paymentRequest.off('paymentmethod'); 
}
 
paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', ...);
```